# Как добавить символы в строчки файла

Tags: c#, строки

В *.txt* файле имеется такая запись:

```
test
test2
test3
```

Мне нужно прочитать этот файл и изменить/добавить в уже существующий текст символ **"** и **,** (запятая)
Должно получиться так:

```
"test",
"test2",
"test3",
```

Как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: И в чем у вас трудности? Даже банальный `.Select(x=>$"\"{x}\",");` справиться с этим... Попробуйте для начала решить сами задачу, а уж потом напрягайте людей...

Answer (score 3):

Почитать:

- https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php LINQ
- https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.5.php Чтение и запись текстовых 
  файлов. StreamReader и StreamWriter

Само решение данной задачи:

```
private static async Task Main()
        {
           List<string> lan = new List<string>
            {
                "Roma",
                "Rita",
                "Dima"
            };
        var readList = new List<string>();
        string writePath = @"D:\SomeDir2\test.txt";

        //Создание\пересоздание нового файла и запись в него
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                foreach (string n in lan) { await sw.WriteLineAsync(n); }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Запись выполнена");
        }

        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }

        //Считывает текст из файла
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(writePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null) { readList.Add(line); }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Чтение выполнено");
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }

        //создает объкт типа Linq.Enumerable с нужными изменениями 
        //(Select: определяет проекцию выбранных значений)
        var newName = readList.Select(x => $"\"{x}\",");

        //Перезаписывает файл
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                foreach (string n in newName) { await sw.WriteLineAsync(n); }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Перезапись выполнена");
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }

        ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Как насчет `File.WriteAllLines(myfile, File.ReadAllLines(myfile).Select(x=>$"\"{x}\","));`?

Comment: @tym32167 Нет предела совершенству, спасибо!